# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocking Ajax requests in ASP.Net WebMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cross-origin-read-blocking

In the ASP.Net application I am developing, I have encountered a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error (the console does not display any specific information, frustratingly), which oddly enough seems to appear only in specific circumstances:

- Only when I upload the application files to the production environment i.e. the actual website and not when I debug the application via Visual Studio
  (which, as you may guess, has resulted in considerable frustration)
- Seems to happen then fix itself randomly upon trying a few more times

This happens when I click the "checkout" button - the application is an e-commerce website.

Here's the Ajax code that seems to be problematic:

```
$("#FldCart").val(JSON.stringify(cartArray));
$("#FldClientData").val(JSON.stringify(clientData));

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checkout.aspx/InsertCart",
                data: "{ cart: '" + $("#FldCart").val() + "', cd: '" + $("#FldClientData").val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    this.disabled = 'false'; // this is simply a reverse of a "true" setting set previously to prevent the form being submitted twice by accident
                    localStorage.setItem("activeCart", []);
                    window.location.replace("/checkoutcomplete.aspx");
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    this.disabled = 'false';
                    window.location.replace("/ordererror.aspx");
                }
            });
```

I have, for context, also included the code in which I read the local storage and put the data in hidden fields so I can send them as strings in the JSON request - it sounds a bit silly, but it was a workaround to an issue I was facing where the data didn't get parsed correctly. Naturally this is part of a JQuery click function, which has not been included for brevity; the rest of it is simply some null checks and object parsing that seems to be working without any issues.

As the console doesn't seem to display any additional information that I can base my research on and I am not sending data to an external API, I cannot figure out what's randomly causing this error...

Comment: The term you are looking for is CORS, not CORB. Cross origin resource sharing.

Comment: I copy/pasted the very message I am getting on the Chrome console!

Comment: Does not change anything of what I said.

Comment: Well the mystery here is that there's no cross-origin requests anyway - I'm not calling a third party API but my own code...